# leaflet won't show wmts-tiles correct

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to use leaflet with a wmts-service without plugin.
here the very basic setup:

<-- language: javascript -->

```
map = L.map('mymap').setView([50.884639, 6.095102], 5);
L.tileLayer('https://www.wmts.nrw.de/geobasis/wmts_nw_dop20/tiles/nw_dop20/EPSG_25832_16/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpeg').addTo(map);

//https://www.wmts.nrw.de/geobasis/wmts_nw_dop20/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml
```

-> [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hans_classen/3fvfy9tc/2/)

My problem: the map won't focus in the right position. when manually scrolled/focused in place it displays correct.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your WMTS service is in EPSG 25832, which is not included by default in Leaflet. ([List of available CRS by default](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#crs-crs))

You will have to define it first, or use a plugin like [Proj4Leaflet](https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet) to define the map CRS.

Comment: thx for taking the time :) the service also allows for EPSG:3857, but this does not bring any results ... within the map